# Error getting image with "image-to-base-64" in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, base64, image-conversion

I'm using the package "[image-to-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64)" to convert images from URLs to base64 and I am getting the following error when trying to fetch images:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at imageToBase64Browser (browser.js:11:1)
    at convertImage (mealPlanTablePDF.tsx:265:28)
    at imageUrlToBase64 (mealPlanTablePDF.tsx:279:5)
    at mealPlanTablePDF.tsx:346:114
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at mealPlanTablePDF.tsx:340:88
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at mealPlanTablePDF.tsx:333:51
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MyDocument (mealPlanTablePDF.tsx:321:41)
    at renderWithHooks (react-reconciler.development.js:6036:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-reconciler.development.js:8570:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-reconciler.development.js:9938:1)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-reconciler.development.js:15754:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-reconciler.development.js:14693:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-reconciler.development.js:14669:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-reconciler.development.js:14265:1)
    at react-reconciler.development.js:1931:1
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:697:1)
    at runWithPriority (react-reconciler.development.js:1881:1)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-reconciler.development.js:1926:1)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-reconciler.development.js:1914:1)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-reconciler.development.js:13704:1)
    at Object.updateContainer (react-reconciler.development.js:17101:1)
    at updateContainer (react-pdf.browser.es.js:5944:1)
    at pdf (react-pdf.browser.es.js:5924:1)
    at generatePDFDocument (chosenMealPlanDesktop.tsx:196:31)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396:1)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507:1)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413:1)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889:1)
```

It seems to work fine when I test the URL in runkit, so I'm thinking it's my implementation, which is as follows:

```
const imageUrlToBase64 = (imgURL: string) => {
    let imageB64: string = "";
    
    const convertImage = async () => {
        await imageToBase64(imgURL)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                imageB64 = response
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error) => {
                console.log(`error fetching: ${imgURL}`)
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
    }

    convertImage();

    return imageB64;
}
```

Is this the correct method?

Comment: What value are you passing in `imgURL`?

Comment: @juliomalves - for example "https://via.placeholder.com/125/000000/FF0000?text=place+holder"

Comment: Your likely getting a CORS error. Check the network tab in your browser to see why it failed to fetch.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually doing anything because you are not waiting for `imageToBase64` to return.

`imageUrlToBase64` is just swallowing the async operation. The code below will work but not you have to make the caller async aware

```js
const imageUrlToBase64 = async (imgURL: string) => {
    let imageB64: string = "";
    
    const convertImage = async () => {
        await imageToBase64(imgURL)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                imageB64 = response
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error) => {
                console.log(`error fetching: ${imgURL}`)
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
    }

    await convertImage();

    return imageB64;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error with this

Comment: for example - "https://via.placeholder.com/125/000000/FF0000?text=place+holder"

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd write your function:

```js
const imageUrlToBase64 = (imgURL: string) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        imageToBase64(imgURL)
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    return resolve(response)
                }
            )
            .catch(
                (error) => {
                    console.log(`error fetching: ${imgURL}`)
                    console.log(error)
                    return reject(error)
                }
            )
    })
}
```

**The main issue here though, is with the image URL you are trying to request.**

The image URL at "via.placeholder.com/125/000000/FF0000?text=place+holder" does not have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) enabled for the origin/domain you are trying to run this code from.

The server for "via.placeholder.com" would need to return a response header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <your_domain_here>` for you to successfully request that image resource in a browser environment.

Try your code with the following image URL instead (it will work, as it has CORS enabled): https://picsum.photos/200

To get around this you could run the code on your server instead and do the base64 conversion there.

Or, if you just need to run this locally and want it to work in the browser you could use a plugin like this (for Google Chrome) to disable CORS security checks in your browser: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

The snippet below has a working implementation of your code. Run it & try testing the base64 conversion with the following URLs:

- https://picsum.photos/200
- https://via.placeholder.com/125/000000/FF0000?text=place+holder

```js
const imageUrlToBase64 = (imgURL) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        imageToBase64(imgURL)
            .then(
                (response) => {
                    return resolve(response)
                }
            )
            .catch(
                (error) => {
                    console.log(`error fetching: ${imgURL}`)
                    console.log(error)
                    return reject(error)
                }
            )
    })
}

$('#convert').click(async function(event){
    $('#output').val('')
    
    var url = $('#url').val()
    var base64 = await imageUrlToBase64(url)
    
    $('#output').val(base64)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/image-to-base64@2.2.0/browser.js"></script>

<input id="url" style="width:80%;" placeholder="Input Image URL">
<br><br>
<button id="convert">Convert</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="output" style="width:80%;"></textarea>
```